# Is it possible to calculate financials on indexes?

Tags: financial-statements

I want to calculate financials on a broad market index, S&P 500.  For example, `VOO` tracks the S&P.  I want to know the cumulative averages for:

Diluted Shares Outstanding
Total Assets
Total Intangible Assets

Technically, I could download the income sheet/balance statement for every stock listed in the S&P and run these numbers myself.  However, this is highly impractical.  Is there an online resource for getting these numbers?

Comment: The headline question "Is it possible to calculate financials on indexes?" doesn't quite match the body " Is there an online resource for getting these numbers?" - Obviously, anything can be calculated, and it's common to hear the CNBC folk talking about S&P earnings as if the S&P were a $2000 stock and had an earnings number. Of course, that's how market P/E is also calculated.

Comment: I do not want to exclude any practical means to calculate the numbers.  I understand it can be calculated and alluded to such.  However, I stated its impractical to run these numbers by hand (and error prone), particularly quarterly.  I'm open to online resources, API's, subscription services, newspapers, etc.  I certainly prefer free.